# google maps iframe class cover text above and doesn't respect dimension

Tags: css, wordpress, google-maps, class, iframe

I've embed a google maps iframe giving it a class for a responsive behavior:

```css
.google-maps {
            padding-bottom: 55%; 
            height: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    
        .google-maps iframe {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100% !important;
            height: 100% !important;
        }
```

```html
<div class="google-maps">

<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d7325331.382945205!2d12.835158178438968!3d26.299870988416156!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x13a892d98ece010d%3A0xfa076041c7f9c22a!2sLibya!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1529409655794" width="350" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

In responsive mode it work, but when I try to put a text above or under the iframe, the text is covered by the map, and the map doesn't respect the dimension that I give to it like `width=450` `height=300`.
When I remove the class, the text and the dimension given work, but of course the map is not responsive anymore.

Someone could help me?
Thank a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Do not change the iframe css
remove this

```
.google-maps iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

and do this

```
.google-maps {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px // change this with media queries for different screen sizes
}
```

Btw it the style fully depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place the iframe inside the `.google-maps` you have to add the `position: relative;` to the `.google-maps`

```
 .google-maps {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 350px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

it will fit the iframe inside the `google-maps` div.

but better is don't try to resize the iframe use them as provided by the google or you can create your custom google map from here [google map developeres](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple).